# Change All Keys in a XML Node in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have 2 XML Files. Both are pretty much the same, but with different key values.  Both look like the example below, but with different values:

```xml
<SMSServerConf>
  <IP>localhost</IP>
  <Port>10010</Port>
  <Provider>3</Provider>
  <Link>192.168.0.146:2775</Link>
  <UserName>smppclient1</UserName>
  <Password>password</Password>
  <Apiid>smppclient1</Apiid>
  <Encoding>0</Encoding>
  <Ton>1</Ton>
  <Npi>1</Npi>
  <ValidityPeriod>20</ValidityPeriod>
  <ValidityPeriodEnable>true</ValidityPeriodEnable>
  <SenderName></SenderName>
</SMSServerConf>
```

Currently I use the code below to insert the values from one file to another:

```bsh
$s_xml = [xml](Get-Content $s_location)
$d_xml = [xml](Get-Content $d_location)
$data = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.IP = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.IP
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Port = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Port
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Provider = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Provider
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Link = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Link
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.UserName = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.UserName
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Password = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Password
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Apiid = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Apiid
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Encoding = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Encoding
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Ton = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Ton
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Npi = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.Npi
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.ValidityPeriod = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.ValidityPeriod
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.ValidityPeriodEnable = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.ValidityPeriodEnable
$d_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.SenderName = $s_xml.Configuration.SMSServerConf.SenderName
$d_xml.Save($d_location)
```

At this point it looks like I will have to maintain the script every time key is added or removed. Is it possible to just indicate the node name and then iterate through each key and change the value instead of explicitly state every key separately?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just replace the `<SMSServerConf>` node?

Comment: `$d_xml = [xml](Get-Content $d_location)` this is the wrong way to load an XML file. It looks as easy and straightforward as it is wrong. Never do that. XML files can have many different encodings. `Get-Content` does not detect the file encoding, and you are not specifying it either. XML parsers automatically detect the file encoding. Use a parser to load XML files. `$xml_d = New-Object xml; $xml_d.Load($d_location)`.

Comment: I disagree. There's nothing wrong with using `[xml](Get-Content ...)` as long as PowerShell is able to determine the encoding (e.g. via the BOM).

Comment: Except that it doesn't, and XML files do not require a BOM, either. Loading XML as text is always wrong. There is an intricate mechanism of file encoding detection built into XML parsers. Circumventing that is stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace the entire content of a node it'd be simpler to just replace the entire node:

```
[xml]$d_xml = Get-Content $d_location
[xml]$s_xml = Get-Content $s_location

$n1 = $d_xml.SelectSingleNode('/Configuration/SMSServerConf')
$n2 = $s_xml.SelectSingleNode('/Configuration/SMSServerConf')
$parent = $n1.ParentNode

# remove existing node
$parent.RemoveChild($n1) | Out-Null

# add node from source XML
$parent.AppendChild($d_xml.ImportNode($n2, $true)) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Does the AppendChild will also save it on d_location XML ? or do i still need to save using $d_xml.Save($d_location)  ?

Comment: `AppendChild()` just inserts the imported node into the XML structure. You still need to save it to make the modification persistent.